# Get node ID in a form submit

Tags: nodes, forms

I am struggling with how to get node id in my user_register_form_submit.
I need to get the node id of the node where my form is, let me explain :

I have created a tpl for my user register form in order to print it in nodes of a special content type, those nodes prepopulate my form and helps to create users, I need this node id to delete the node after submiting the form wich means delete the node after a user is created.

here is my hook :

```
    function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        if($form_id == 'user_register_form'){
            $form['#submit'][] = 'user_register_form_submit';
        }
    }

    function user_register_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
    // print the node id
    }
```

Last thing, I'm working with Drupal 7.
Thanks !

Comment: So you want a node id in user registration form, to know what node user was viewing when he registered? May be hard. Especially that there is no guarantee that there will be any node at all, and if so, that there will be only one. I wonder what your reason is, maybe there is an easier solution to achieve your business goal.

Comment: Why you are embeding user register form in node? what is your requirement?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I just need to know the node id where the form was submitted to delete this node.

My goal is to create a custom way to create users, I allow anonymous users to submit a form (with my content type) and I take this data and prepopulate it in my user register form, so the thing is for each content of this content type there is my user register form.

Comment: @ARUN I'm trying to create a light back office for a client where he just need to validate his users (Drupal default admin approbation is not a solution for this)

Comment: @MouhyeddineBourabaa, In Drupal 7, you can attach `field api` with `user registration` form, so you can implement same validation with `user registration` whatever you have implemented with `content type`.

Comment: What you could do is on submit of that node add user programatically and then it would be as simple as $form_state['nid'].

Comment: @sly Thanks for your answer, unfortunately no, my user register form is not linked to a node, I output my form with php code and when I paste the $form_state['nid'] I get and undefined index.

Comment: you embedding the form in node? node is coming dynamically?

Comment: function MODULE_form_CONTENT_TYPE_NAME_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'my_custom_submit';
}

function my_custom_submit(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
   print $form_state['nid'];
}

that will for sure print the nid and there you can add user programmatically. It is a different aproach to what you set out to do.

Comment: @ARUN Yes, I print my form in every node of that content type and with a javascript script I prepopulate my user register form so I just have to sumbit my form to create my user, when it's done I don't need that node anymore, that's why I need the id in the submit form.

Comment: @sly I tried your code and I have this error :  Missing argument 3 for user_register_form_submit() and the Undefined index.

Comment: please provide your user register form embeding code.

Comment: @ARUN I put this code in a block (with php code) and I display this block only for my nodes so here is the code :

<?php
  $form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form');
  print drupal_render($form);
?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more line below your *user register form* embed code,

```
$form = drupal_get_form('user_register_form'); 
print drupal_render($form);

echo "<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#user-register-form').append('<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"nid\" value=".arg(1).">');
  });
</script>";
```

Then you will get the `nid` of node inside user register submit function like this:

```
function user_register_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // print the node id
  echo $form_state['input']['nid'];
}
```

Also you can do it with `hook_form_alter`. Add one hidden field and assign `nid` as value for it.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_register_form') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'user_register_form_submit';
    $form['nid'] = array(
      '#value' => arg(1),
      '#type' => 'hidden',
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use JavaScript, use form_alter for it!

Comment: @ram4nd This works for me, how can I do it with form_alter ?

Comment: Add the hidden value to the form with form alter not JavaScript. I can't explain the whole hook system here in comments.

Answer (score 11):

For Drupal 8 Add your custom submit handler in form alter:

```
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_custom_node_form_submit';
```

And add custom submit handler:

```
function _custom_node_form_submit($form, \Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  echo $form_state->getValue('nid');
}
```

Comment: For me the new `nid` is also available in `$form['node']->nid` and `$form_state['values']['nid']` at this point. However, interestingly if using `$form['#submit'][]` instead of `$form['actions']['submit']['#submit']`, the newly created node's `nid` will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [Niks](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/96653/292) answer.

```
function custom_module_form_validate(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // This will print the node id.
  var_dump(arg(1)); 
}
```

I didn't actually know this until I tried it just now. Credit should go to Niks.

Note; From the [Drupal docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) arg(), "Returns a component of the current Drupal path." In this case the second. That means that this **will not** work on all forms because not all forms will use the node path.

**Edit: Incorporating info from MPD's comment below**
Avoid use of this function where possible, as resulting code is hard to read. In menu callback functions, attempt to use named arguments. See the explanation in menu.inc for how to construct callbacks that take arguments. When attempting to use this function to load an element from the current path, e.g. loading the node on a node page, use [menu_get_object](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7)() instead.

Comment: arg() is a bad function, and should be avoided.  Use `menu_get_object()` instead.