# Is it possible to get the node ID of the node that will be created?

Tags: 8, nodes

Trying to pass some information to third party API, every time a new node is created.

So far I have managed to identify the node insert/create when a node is created in `hook_node_presave()`. Done it by using `empty($node->id())`.

Now I want to anticipate what the node ID will be once the node is saved. Is it possible to get the node ID  before the node is created?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get node ID in a form submit](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96634/get-node-id-in-a-form-submit)

Comment: I needed hook insert for passing new node field values along with its id. Used presave because, for some reason I was convinced that node_insert from Drupal 7 is deprecated and no more used in D8 .  Jdrupal 's pointer to use hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert helped me sort my query. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.2.x) which is called after the node has been saved.

Function description:

> This hook runs once the entity has been stored. Note that hook implementations may not alter the stored entity data.